# The definite article for inventions

Tags: definite-article

Why do we need to use the definite article when we are speaking about inventions like in the sentence below:

> Alexander Bell invented the telephone.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Btw, **Invented radio** doesn't require any article.

Comment: @SovereignSun: True, but [*Marconi invented **the** radio*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Marconi+invented+the+radio%22) gets significantly more hits than [*Marconi invented radio*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Marconi+invented+radio%22) in Google Books. I must say I don't much like the article there though, since what he came up with wasn't exactly what we'd refer to as ***a radio*** (besides which, *there were no radio stations to listen to on it!* :) And *radio **waves*** weren't exactly invented - they already existed.

Comment: It seems to vary depending on the noun. Compare this question about ["invented paper"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11792/usage-of-articles-definite-article-or-zero-article)